# How can I get more exact data-points from a visual studio load test?

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

When load-testing in Visual Studio the results are reported with snapshots of data using a resolution in time as indicated by the *Sample Rate* parameter. However I find that this is rarely a desirable way to look at the results. It would be much more useful to have the actual timestamp of when something happens rather than timestamps with a constant interval. For example for *Page Response Time* it would be much more useful to have the timestamp of when the response is received.

I currently obtain data by exporting graphs to csv. This gives me data in the form:

```
"Elapsed Time","Page1Time","Page2Time"
"00:00"       ,         "",         ""
"00:05"       ,         "",         ""
"00:10"       ,  "0,36325",         ""
"00:15"       ,         "",   "0,2825"
```

Because of the constant time-intervals used there will often be large gaps in the data with no data points, as well as general poor accuracy. I would much rather prefer to have a timestamp for each datapoint so that every page time contains both the response time and the timestamp:

```
"Timestamp1","Page1Time","Timestamp2","Page2Time"
"00:09.654"  , "0,36325", "00:14.345",   "0,2825"
```

I don't need the exact format as above, just any format where each point of data is represented by both it's own timestamp and y-axis value.

As a last resort it should be possible to implement my own logging for each request/response or other data that I need, however it would save me a lot of time if there is a simpler way to get the data the way I want it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know all the data is recorded in the load test database. It is just an SQL database and you can write you own queries etc to examine its contents. There is a [description of the tables and columns](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/slumley/2010/02/12/description-of-tables-and-columns-in-vs-2010-load-test-database/) in the database; some changes have been made for more recent Visual Studio versions, but that blog is the best description currently available.

It may be necessary to set the `Timing details storage` to `All individual details` in the run settings.

Logs of the individual web tests have additional details. Altering the 
altering `Save log frequency for completed tests` in the run settings allows logs for successful tests to be retained.